# How Can I Control Access to a file in distributed environment?

Tags: jgroups

In my setup there will be 2 or more servers which will poll a particular directory for a file.As soon as a server finds it it will process the file.
I want to ensure that only one server access this file at a time so that same file does not get processed twice.
I don't have much pointers as of now to proceed .

Few POCs in progress are creating something like .lock file another one I am working on is using Jgroups.

It's a common problem and will like to know the popular approaches to this .

Any suggestion is appreciated .

Comment: There is `LockService` in JGroups - http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/user-building-blocks.html#LockService.

Comment: Will you suggest that JGroup approach is right way to prove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After implementing Distributed lock service we encountered an issue , what was happening is that unlocking was done by a different thread rather than the one that locked it , So locks were not getting released . 
So then I have switched over to Leader Election and used Jgroups logic that first node will be the leader.So leader node is coordinating my actions and I dont need to put a lock instead just distribute the work.